# Decorator pattern on the real example in C++

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, decorator

Hello I tried to implement "Decorator" pattern on the real example, but I can't decorate my object **(Burger* b)** in client side (in main function). When I type "new Cheese" in ConcretteBurger() - Visual Studio shows me an *Error: "no defauls constructor exist for class "Cheese""*

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Burger{
public:
    virtual int get_cost() = 0;
};

class ConcretteBurger: public Burger{
public:
    int get_cost(){
        return 3;
    }
};

class BurgerDecorator:public Burger{
private:
    Burger *b;

public:
    BurgerDecorator(Burger* bb){
      bb = b;
    }
    ~BurgerDecorator(){
        delete b;
    }
    int get_cost(){
        return b->get_cost();
    }
};

class Tomato:public BurgerDecorator{
public:
    Tomato(Burger *b):BurgerDecorator(b){

    }
    int get_cost(){

        return BurgerDecorator::get_cost() + 4;
    }
};
class Cheese:public BurgerDecorator{
public:
    Cheese(Burger *b):BurgerDecorator(b){}
    int get_cost(){
        return BurgerDecorator::get_cost()+3;

    }
};

int main(){
     Burger* b = new ConcretteBurger(new Cheese);
     cout<<b->get_cost();

     system("pause");
}
```

Second problem that I didn't understood the concept **:BurgerDecorator(b)** after declaration of function. For example:

```
 Tomato(Burger *b):BurgerDecorator(b){}
```

I didn't find it in C++ books .

**Thank you**

Comment: The only constructor `Cheese` has is `Cheese(Burger* b)`.  Therefore, you can only construct it with a `Burger*`, and can't make it without any arguments.  If you want to be able to construct it without giving it a `Burger*`, either give it a constructor that takes no arguments (`Cheese()`), or give its constructor a default argument to use when none is supplied (such as `Cheese(Burger* b = new Burger)`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems in your code.
First the initializing in BurgerDecorator:

```
BurgerDecorator(Burger* bb){
  b = bb;
}
```

Second the constructor of ConcreteBurger has only the standard constructor. So you can instantiate just burger without arguments:

```
Burger* b = new ConcretteBurger();
```

and pass this burger to a decorator, because the decorator has a constructor with an argumentlist of Burgers (in other words: the chess decorates the burger):

```
Burger* decorator = new Cheese(b);
cout << decorator ->get_cost() << endl;
```

at least your understanding of ** :BurgerDecorator(b)**:

This will call the constructor of the base class and pass the argument. Its called *initializer lists*. [Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) you can read more about it.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it works :) , Could you please explain Tomato(Burger *b):BurgerDecorator(b){}   and Cheese(Burger *b):BurgerDecorator(b){} part of code.

Answer (score 2):

In `main` function you should do this:

```
Burger* b = new Cheese(new ConcretteBurger);
```

Instead of this:

```
Burger* b = new ConcretteBurger(new Cheese);
```

The cheese *decorates* the burger, not the opposite. More in general, the decorator class takes a reference to the decorated class and not the opposite.

Note also that the constructor of `BurgerDecorator` has a bug. It should be:

```
BurgerDecorator(Burger* bb){
  b = bb;
}
```

Or even better:

```
BurgerDecorator(Burger* bb): b{bb} {}
```

Instead of `bb = b;` as it is in your example.

Finally, add a virtual destructor to your base class to avoid leaks:

```
class Burger{
public:
    virtual ~Burger() = default;
    virtual int get_cost() = 0;
};
```

See your code once fixed on [wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/es53sMfEZKuNWDyb).

Comment: @SuleymanSuleyman-zade You're welcome. Feel free to accept this or one of the other answers if they solved your problem. This will help future readers to find easily the information they are looking for.